# How can I maximise my chances of seeing a wild wombat?

Tags: animals, australia

What can I do to see wombats in the wild?  I'm aware of places that have wombats as I have seen their droppings, but what can I do to see wild wombats?

Comment: The first step is to get yourself to Australia.

Comment: @olin step 1 is done

Comment: I eventually saw one, and it was just wandering along the side of the road in the middle of the day.

Answer (score 7):

I know nothing about wombats, but I do stalk a particular wild animal here in my part of the world. Here is some general advice.

Scat is a good start. Are there areas where it is more concentrated?

Get well away from human activity. Wild animals avoid us, some more so than others. I gather that wombats are on the shy side.

When you get out there, be quiet. It is difficult for some to fathom just how noisy we are. Move slowly and only move a few steps at a time. Can you hear birds singing in your location? You are starting to blend in. If they are alarming or silent, the wild creatures know that you are around. Rain can be helpful for stalking wild animals in two ways. 1) It makes dead vegetation less crunchy 2) it creates ambient noise that can mask a lot of low level sound.

Also consider your scent. How well do wombats smell? You can try to approach an area from down wind. Some hunters do their best to de-scent themselves and their equipment.

If they have good vision, you might consider camouflage clothing to give you an edge.